# Ruby OAuth2 timeout error getting Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I posted this of the issues page for the doorkeeper gem, but looking at it, I wonder if I should post here, any help would be amazing as I am completely stuck

I have been following the wiki on doorkeeper and doing the "Testing your provider with OAuth2 gem" (https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-your-provider-with-OAuth2-gem)

I am running rails 5.1.4, ruby 2.4.1, doorkeeper gem 4.2.6 and oauth2 v1.4.0

I am having issues trying to do what is done in the testing wiki in code, which is get an auth token

My sessions controller:

```
def new
  session[:state] = 'some state sent from amazon'
  session[:client_id] = 'some client id'
  session[:client_secret] = 'some client secret'
  session[:redirect_uri] = "#{request.base_url}/oauth/callback"
end

def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    if user.activated?
      log_in user
        redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => session[:redirect_uri])
    end
 end
end

#route for /oauth/cllback comes here
def callback 
  token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => session[:redirect_uri])
  # testing print to screen
  render json: token
end

private 
 def client
   OAuth2::Client.new(session[:client_id], session[:client_secret], :site => request.base_url)
 end
```

So as a user i log in, I authorise the app and then it times out and I get the following log for the whole flow:

```
Started GET "/login?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&state=<amazon state>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpitangui.amazon.com%2Fapi%2Fskill%2Flink%2FM2X1TLJOHDU07S" for 5.175.83.20 at 2017-10-23 13:36:35 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"client_id"=>"<client_id>", "response_type"=>"code", "state"=>"<amazon state>", "redirect_uri"=>"https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/M2X1TLJOHDU07S"}
  Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (36.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 121ms (Views: 107.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)

Started POST "/login" for 5.175.83.20 at 2017-10-23 13:40:35 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aR03Eo+jxzN+oDPrnOevHn6moTCSePoLAi2Ncc7pKbtxVQa6lLu+IzdEsfzrexpJVm6MdOugIQICyN2ZNS7hgw==", "session"=>{"email"=>"me@daviesp.co.uk", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log In"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "me@daviesp.co.uk"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F3751d64e.ngrok.io%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code
Completed 302 Found in 67ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Started GET "/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F3751d64e.ngrok.io%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code" for 5.175.83.20 at 2017-10-23 13:40:36 +0100
Processing by Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"client_id"=>"<client_id>", "redirect_uri"=>"https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback", "response_type"=>"code"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "6067fbe8f36b4343aa297ce76348e868f9ea04b04841adb411d0885c491c1d48"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "oauth_access_tokens".* FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE "oauth_access_tokens"."application_id" = $1 AND "oauth_access_tokens"."resource_owner_id" = $2 AND "oauth_access_tokens"."revoked_at" IS NULL ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT $3  [["application_id", 11], ["resource_owner_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Doorkeeper::AccessGrant Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "oauth_access_grants" WHERE "oauth_access_grants"."token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["token", "a6bd0459570f1e0116ca6b2cade1e60ae83ba439d3c70b750046cfffe3cc85e4"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "oauth_access_grants" ("resource_owner_id", "application_id", "token", "expires_in", "redirect_uri", "created_at", "scopes") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["resource_owner_id", 1], ["application_id", 11], ["token", "a6bd0459570f1e0116ca6b2cade1e60ae83ba439d3c70b750046cfffe3cc85e4"], ["expires_in", 600], ["redirect_uri", "https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback"], ["created_at", "2017-10-23 12:40:36.235539"], ["scopes", ""]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback?code=a6bd0459570f1e0116ca6b2cade1e60ae83ba439d3c70b750046cfffe3cc85e4
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)

Started GET "/oauth/callback?code=[FILTERED]" for 5.175.83.20 at 2017-10-23 13:40:36 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#oauth_call as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Started POST "/oauth/token" for 5.175.83.20 at 2017-10-23 13:40:37 +0100
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60406ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Faraday::TimeoutError (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

Cant for the life of me figure out why it works in `irb` but not in code.  Here is what i do in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'oauth2'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
irb(main):003:0* client_id    = '6067fbe8f36b4343aa297ce76348e868f9ea04b04841adb411d0885c491c1d48'
=> "6067fbe8f36b4343aa297ce76348e868f9ea04b04841adb411d0885c491c1d48"
irb(main):004:0> client_secret       = '937088f4b7579b8922ad02518477da7be699958df1b1e8a85da34f2e8b4ce086'
=> "937088f4b7579b8922ad02518477da7be699958df1b1e8a85da34f2e8b4ce086"
irb(main):005:0> redirect_uri   = 'https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback'
=> "https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback"
irb(main):006:0> site = 'https://3751d64e.ngrok.io'
=> "https://3751d64e.ngrok.io"
irb(main):007:0> state = 'some state'
=> "some state"
irb(main):008:0> client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, :site => site)
=> #<OAuth2::Client:0x007fa61414c4b0 @id="6067fbe8f36b4343aa297ce76348e868f9ea04b04841adb411d0885c491c1d48", @secret="937088f4b7579b8922ad02518477da7be699958df1b1e8a85da34f2e8b4ce086", @site="https://3751d64e.ngrok.io", @options={:authorize_url=>"/oauth/authorize", :token_url=>"/oauth/token", :token_method=>:post, :auth_scheme=>:request_body, :connection_opts=>{}, :connection_build=>nil, :max_redirects=>5, :raise_errors=>true}>
irb(main):009:0> client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri)
=> "https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=6067fbe8f36b4343aa297ce76348e868f9ea04b04841adb411d0885c491c1d48&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F3751d64e.ngrok.io%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code"
```

even If i put that uri into browser and it returns the access token:

```
{"token_type":"bearer","created_at":1508763209,"access_token":"38282cae5191923f1f358aece869e237d4d9742cdd7c918ae63104c57807a826","refresh_token":null,"expires_at":1508770409}
```

Again any help would be amazing!

Comment: The redirect URI you are getting back from the call in the controller is certainly different from the one you are getting back in the console, which leads me to think what's in `session[:redirect_uri]` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Put a breakpoint just before you call `client.auth_code.authorize_url`, and make the same call, but with your redirect_uri set to 'https://3751d64e.ngrok.io/oauth/callback' and see what you get back.

Comment: I changed from using puma(rails server) to pow and it works

Answer (score 0):

So I found in my Dev Environment, if i stop using puma and rails server and started using POW, the issue went away.  I checked if puma was running as single thread but it was running 5 threads, so not sure why this was happening.